# How to fetch image from google drive with react-google-drive-picker

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am currently working on adding a new functionality to my website, [picexpert.net](https://picexpert.net/), which involves retrieving images from Google Drive and resizing them. For this purpose, I have implemented a library called "react-google-drive-picker."

Upon selecting images from Google Drive, the library returns an object containing information about the selected files. Here is an example of the object:

```
{
    "id": "1-0PtJ8DevSEgvwuHoB0PJo5uYxWFwS9e",
    "serviceId": "docs",
    "mimeType": "image/png",
    "name": "00000-895002532-cat, (masterpiece,best quality_1.5).png",
    "description": "",
    "type": "photo",
    "lastEditedUtc": 1686938568207,
    "iconUrl": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/png",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0PtJ8DevSEgvwuHoB0PJo5uYxWFwS9e/view?usp=drive_web",
    "embedUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0PtJ8DevSEgvwuHoB0PJo5uYxWFwS9e/preview?usp=drive_web",
    "sizeBytes": 668921,
    "rotation": 0,
    "rotationDegree": 0,
    "parentId": "1-D6DpWA6EMiWZTdeZOX72Iv77YcgGL1r"
}
```

My problem is that I am unable to fetch the image using either the "url" or "embedUrl." I have even tried using the "id" in the following format:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?download=view&id=<fileId>
```

Unfortunately, this approach has not yielded the desired result.

I am seeking guidance on how to obtain the image blob or a File object from the provided information. Any assistance or insights would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: can i see your code please

Comment: Which code do you wanna see?